# Last Array Dictionary Object is Null - Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

A bit of a strange problem I've run into. I'm looping through an array of message objects which contain various information including date, topic data, and user content. For each index I grab three items and create a dictionary which then gets pushed into a new array. Once the loop has completed the new array has all of the proper information, with the exception of the last index. Of the three dictionary values in the last index, the last item (date object) is null. I've worked around the issue by looping using a forEach as an alternative like so:

Original non-working method:

```
var tempArray = [];  

for(var k = 0; k < msgArray.length; k++) {
     var newDict = {msg:msgArray[k], topId:msgArray[k].topicId, created:msgArray[k].dateTime};
     tempArray.push(newDict);
}
```

Alternative working method:

```
var tempArray = [];

msgArray.forEach(function(messa){
    var newDict = {msg:messa, topId:messa.topicId, created:messa.dateTime};
    tempArray.push(newDict);
});
```

And a capture from the debugger:
[image: bad temp array]

Alternative method capture from debugger:
[image: good temp array]

The workaround works fine, but it would be nice if someone could explain why this is occurring, just for my own learning/curiosity. I appreciate any comments. Thanks.

Edit: Although it would seem like there is something fishy with msgArray, it's a run of the mill array with valid content in each index...structured like so:

msgArray[0]
- message (Object)
- topicId (String)
- dateTime (Date)

...and so on. I would think if there were an issue with the original array it would effect both methods of parsing out into dictionaries, however it does not. Part of the reason this is such an odd occurrence.

Comment: I think there's probably something else going wrong, because those two pieces of code would do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I think the problem is with your msgArray, show us that.

Comment: @Pointy: I agree they should both behave entirely the same, but they do not. The msgArray is as basic as it gets. There is nothing visibly wrong with it. The only consistency is the null on the last index every time.

Comment: Well, from that debugger output, the value of the "created" property on the last entry is *not* `null`.

Comment: Ok 'undefined'. Either way there is nothing in there.

Comment: In your debugger output tempArray[4][created] shows 'object' instead of 'date'..I think the problem with msgArray?

Comment: What happens when you log `typeof tempArray[4].created` ?

Comment: @Pointy: Good call on logging it (shame on me for not trying that). It actually prints out the date. This must then be a problem with the IDE/debugger I'm using (WebStorm). I'll inquire with them and post an answer.